# how to insert textView in an imageView to be able to save it in device

Tags: java, android, android-studio

well I explain the image comes from another activity and I show it here with the textview on top, but when I save the image it is not saved with the text that I place on top of it, I have not found the way to do it, if you can help me thanks.

Seen around there that you have to draw on top of the image but I don't know how, I don't know if there will be another way.

**activity xml**

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="375dp"
        android:layout_height="377dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtPrecio"
        android:layout_width="172dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDescripcion"
        android:layout_width="173dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
</RelativeLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnGuardar"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="43dp"
    android:text="@string/guardar"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

**Activity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

    Button btnGuardar = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btnGuardar);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String[] message = extras.getStringArray("message");

    TextView precio = findViewById(R.id.txtPrecio);
    TextView descripcion = findViewById(R.id.txtDescripcion);


    for(int i=0;i<message.length;i++) {
        precio.setText(message[0]);
        descripcion.setText(message[1]);
    }


    Intent intent = getIntent();
    bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("BitmapImage");

    ImageView imageView2 = this.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    imageView2.setImageBitmap(bitmap);



    btnGuardar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            checkPermissionStorage();
        }
    });

}

private void checkPermissionStorage() {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.P){
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
            if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                guardarFoto();
            }else{
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                        this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        REQUEST_PERMISSION_WRITE_STORAGE
                );
            }
        }else {
            guardarFoto();
        }
    }else{
        guardarFoto();
    }
}


public void guardarFoto() {
    OutputStream fos = null;
    File file = null;

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q){
        ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        String fileName = System.currentTimeMillis() + "image_example";

        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName);
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, "Pictures/MyApp");
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.IS_PENDING, 1);

        Uri collection = MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY);
        Uri imageUri = resolver.insert(collection, values);

        try {
            fos = resolver.openOutputStream(imageUri);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        values.clear();
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.IS_PENDING, 0);
        resolver.update(imageUri, values, null, null);

    }else{
        String imageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString();
        String filename = System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
        file = new File(imageDir, filename);

        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    boolean saved = bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
    if(saved){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Imagen guardada", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    if(fos!=null){
        try {
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    if(file!=null){
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[]{
                file.toString()
        }, null, null);
    }

}
```

Comment: "When I save the image"-  where are you doing that?  You didn't share that code.

Comment: @GabeSechan there it is friend